# How to access specific index in list in jinja2

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Suppose there is list a=[1,2,3,4] in jinja2
and i want to access only 3rd index of list .In other languages we write a[2]
but it shows error in jinja2.

```
    def dashboard(request):
        user = request.user
        staff_detail = []
        staffs = models.Staff.objects.all()

        rec_total = models.Recordings.objects.all().count()
        rec_enquiry = models.Recordings.objects.filter(type=1).count()
        rec_complaint = models.Recordings.objects.filter(type=2).count()

        for staff in staffs:

            st = dict()
            st['staff_detail'] = staff
            st['total_recordings'] = staff.recordings_set.all().count()
            st['enquiry'] = staff.recordings_set.filter(type=1).count()
            st['complaint'] = staff.recordings_set.filter(type=2).count()
            staff_detail.append(st)
        return render(request, 'hackathon/index.html', {
            'staff_detail': staff_detail,
            'rec_total': rec_total,
            'rec_enquiry': rec_enquiry,
            'rec_complaint': rec_complaint,
            'staff_first': staff_detail[0],
        })
```

In html file want only the 1st element of staff_detail currently I write

```
    {{staff_detail[0].staff_detail.name}}
```

but it is showing error
I can only access them using for loop

Comment: What error? How are you calling it?  Why are you making us guess?

Comment: I am actually rendering a list in django template so I want to access only a specific index of list.

Comment: Don't tell us.. show us!

Comment: That seems like it ought to work.  What is the exact error message?

Comment: error was "Could not parse the remainder: '[0].staff_detail.name' ". But I have found the solution it should be written as  `{{staff_detail.0.staff_detail.name}}`

Answer (score 6):

It should be written as  `{{staff_detail.0.staff_detail.name}}`